# Strapi CMS, How can I make a packages (prices list) table?

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, strapi

I am trying to make an API using strapi for a similar table to the one shown below.

I have tried implementing using two collections and setting up a one to many relationships. However, there are some packages which have a text (in my case its price, quantity, or a duration) instead of just a true sign.

Also, I tried to use a component for futures, but that doesn't allow me to add a subtitle to the feature and doesn't allow me to use spaces in the future name.

What is the best way to implement this table in strapi.

I am planning to use strapi admin panel as my main website admin panel (I will modify data using it).

Thanks.

[image: packages table]

Comment: Can you share your 2 collections?

Comment: @ghosh I have deleted them , 
Seems like Strapi doesn't can do additional fields in many to many relationship.

Comment: You would have to do it mannually, see this pull request: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3750
However, currently strapi doesn't show relational fields in the list view, 
But its on the roadmap: 
https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-roadmap/c/49-display-relational-field-in-list-view
For now, Strapi is not the best solution for my project.

Comment: Update: Strapi now displays the relational field in list view

Comment: @BaselAkasha Did you manage this? If so, how did you solve it?

Comment: @Rod I ended up using headless WordPress. I think it is achievable using Strapi but it is not straightforward and not user-friendly. This is a specific use case and there is no plugin that allows you to modify the table in an easy to use interface. You can make your own plugin or use collections and the built-in dashboard to manage and edit the table. You will need three collections: packages, features and packages_features which map the one to many relationships between the packages and features.

Comment: @BaselAkasha Thanks for the quick response! Yeah, I imagined that Strapi is not so much powerful as WordPress for this kind of complex content. I managed to create a table in Strapi with nested and repeatable components, but it is not super user-friendly. Another option that I'm checking is using markdown for generate tables., but still not user-friendly at all.